# Horizontal alignment of multiple glossaries

Tags: horizontal-alignment, glossaries, acronyms

I utilize the `glossaries`package with `acronym` option as well as an self-defined symbols list. Unfortunately, each glossary aligns different horizontally. Is it possible to make them aligned? Otherwise, it looks distracting to me.

[image: vertical glossaries alignment]

Code:

```
  \documentclass[8pt]{scrartcl}

  % LuaLaTeX
  \usepackage{luatextra}

  \usepackage[xindy,style=long,numberline,savewrites=true,acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
  % new group for symbols
  \newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbols}
  \makeglossaries

  % SYMBOLS:
  \newglossaryentry{sy:te}{name=$\text{T}_\text{E}$, description={echo time}, sort=sy-echotime, type=symbolslist}
  \newglossaryentry{sy:tr}{name=$\text{T}_\text{R}$, description={repetition time}, sort=sy-repetitiontime, type=symbolslist}
  % ACRONYMS:
  \newacronym{adc}{ADC}{anlog-to-digital converter}
  \newacronym{peg}{PEG}{polyethylene glycol}

  \begin{document}
  \printglossaries
  Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text
   Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
  .... \gls{peg} .... \gls{adc}
  .... \gls{sy:tr} .... \gls{sy:te}

  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as i was eager to keep `style=long` i came up with something. As Nicola posted you can set `\glssetwidest`for the `alttree` style. Unfortunately, i can't find something similiar for the first entry within `long`. Therefore, i simply put a dummy entry (blank line) to my symbols list (sorted to be at the end of the list):

```
  % blanc entry used for spacing
  \newglossaryentry{sy:space}{name=\makebox[\widthof{ADC-long}][l]{}, description={}, sort=sy-zz, type=symbolslist,nonumberlist}
  \glsadd{sy:space}
```

Not the nicest solution but it works:
[image: horziontal alignment glossaries]

Full Code:

```
  \documentclass[8pt]{scrartcl}

  % LuaLaTeX
  \usepackage{luatextra}
  \usepackage{calc}
  \usepackage[xindy,style=long,numberline,savewrites=true,acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
  % new group for symbols
  \renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}
  \newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbols}
  \renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}
  % remove dot after each description
  \renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
  \makeglossaries

  % SYMBOLS:
  \newglossaryentry{sy:te}{name=$\text{T}_\text{E}$, description={echo time}, sort=sy-echotime, type=symbolslist}
  \newglossaryentry{sy:tr}{name=$\text{T}_\text{R}$, description={repetition time}, sort=sy-repetitiontime, type=symbolslist}
  \newglossaryentry{sy:ga}{name=\gamma, description={gamma}, sort=sy-gamma, type=symbolslist}
  % blanc entry used for spacing
  \newglossaryentry{sy:space}{name=\makebox[\widthof{ADC-long}][l]{}, description={}, sort=sy-zz, type=symbolslist,nonumberlist}
  \glsadd{sy:space}

  % ACRONYMS:
  \newacronym{adc}{ADC-long}{anlog-to-digital converter}
  \newacronym{peg}{PEG}{polyethylene glycol}

  %\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textmd{#1}}
  %\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{#1}
  \glssetwidest{ADC}

  %\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.3\linewidth}
  \begin{document}
  \printglossaries
  \vspace{1cm}
  Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text
   Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.
  .... \gls{peg} .... \gls{adc}
  .... \gls{sy:tr} .... \gls{sy:te} .... \gls{sy:ga}.

  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you use the `alttree` style instead of `long` and set the width of the name field using `\glssetwidest`:

```
\usepackage[xindy,style=alttree,numberline,savewrites=true,acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\glssetwidest{ADC}% widest name
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textmd{#1}}
```

Comment: Mh it sure is a an alternative. Is it possible to avoid setting the abbrevation bold? Some math symbols do not get bold rendering it inconsistent. What still bothers me as well is that long entries (page references exceeding a line) start at the beginning of the next line and not at the explanation indentation (as in `long`). Gonna keep the question open for a little bit longer.

Comment: @bioslime Just redefine `\glsnamefont` to cancel the bold. I've added the code to my answer.

Comment: Also you can use `\glsfindwidesttoplevelname[\acronymtype]` for acronyms and `\glsfindwidesttoplevelname[\glsdefaulttype]` for glossaries I didn't test it but I think you can also use `main` intead of `\glsdefaulttype`